# Google Apps Discord Script repeating prior posts

Tags: google-apps-script, discord, gmail-api, webhooks

I have a script that I'd like to scrape a gmail label and then send off a Discord webhook notification to a channel. It *appears* to work just fine until it's triggered a few times, and then it begins repeating prior emails and skipping new ones -- even though the label switching is being handled properly. I'm not sure if there's something I'm doing wrong with my Google Script and it's keeping variables between triggers or...? Any help would be appreciated.

```
    var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Unposted');
    var posted = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Posted');
    var threads = label.getThreads();

    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        messages = messages.concat(threads[i].getMessages())
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        var message = messages[i];
        Logger.log(message);

        var output = message.getPlainBody();
        Logger.log(output);

        var discordUrl = "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/xxx/xxxxxx";
        var payload = JSON.stringify({content: output});

        var params = {
                method: "POST",
                payload: payload,
                muteHttpExceptions: true,
                contentType: "application/json"
        };

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(discordUrl, params);
    Logger.log(response.getContentText());     

   }

   // Switch labels once the webhook is sent
   posted.addToThreads(threads);
   label.removeFromThreads(threads);

}
```

Comment: How often is your script being run? Could it be possible that the messages that are being repeated are being taken from threads that have had replies since the last run?

Comment: The new replies, when they happen, will have a different username. The email body is just a simple message with a link:


    username has just posted in [threadtitle](threadlink) from forumname


Sometimes the script will echo 2-3 messages that have already been posted and moved to a different label.

Comment: How long between calls are you waiting? It could be that not enough time has elapsed between each call for the last two lines `posted.addToThreads(threads); label.removeFromThreads(threads);` to execute and propagate.

Comment: 5 minutes. How long do they take to propagate?

Comment: Note -- I fixed the username problem. It was a problem with vbulletin. I'm still getting old phantom replies stacking up, sometimes 20-30 minutes after the original notification was posted. It definitely feels like the label changes aren't being respected.

Comment: Have you checked the messages in the Gmail web client to confirm the labels have changed?

Comment: The labels were changing. It's definitely a Gmail issue. I wrote another script that purges the Trash with that label and with the Trash empty, there's no repeating. So, situation solved but there's definitely some significant propagation issues with the way labels and/or Inbox -> Trash is handled.